# A sign that is still up after it no longer applies

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word to describe the following situation: There is a sign up warning people not to do something, but it has been up so long I think it no longer applies, but I'm going to follow it anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add context as to why you think it doesn't apply?

Comment: I can't think of a single word, but the phrase "blindly observe obsolete restrictions" comes to mind, if that helps.

Comment: Are you looking for something like obsolete, expired, outdated, defunct?

Comment: Sorry. Should have been more specific. There is a sign up in a conference room telling us not to use the blackboards because they are under treatment. It has been up for weeks. Thus, it is doubtful that they are still under treatment. I wouldn't use most of these phrases, but "outdated," might fit. I feel like there is a single word though.

Comment: are you thinking of "redundant"? for computer code there is "legacy"

Comment: No. It might qualify as obsolete, though I don't like using that word for this context, but redundant doesn't fit and legacy outside of computer code is not the correct choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word is *out-of-date*. It is an *out-of-date* sign. The sign is *out of date*.

You can also say that it is not *up to date*; it is not an *up-to-date* sign.

You can also say that the sign is *no longer applicable*, or that it *no longer applies*.

None of those expressions are single words, except for the hyphenated forms used as adjectives.

The single words mentioned in @GMB's comment are also applicable: *obsolete*, *outdated*, and *defunct* (though I probably would not apply *defunct* to a sign, myself).

Comment: Obsolete is probably the best choice for single word, but out of date is probably the best descriptor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Oxford Dictionary Online*, the term *[relic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/relic)* means

> An object surviving from an earlier time, especially one of historical or sentimental interest.

While this definition does not explicitly reflect an intent to follow the outdated patterns, the religious connotation invites such an interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is ***time-honored*** (AmE) / ***time-honoured*** (BrE). It implies that something is honored or followed even it is outdated or old-fashioned because it was there for a long time. It is usually applied to ***long-standing*** traditions and customs.

Thus, for your specific example, you might use ***long-standing sign*** as a homonymic pun.

Also, you might use the idiomatic phrase ***live in the past*** for the people with this kind of mindset.

> Have old-fashioned or outdated ideas and attitudes: *we aren’t here to cater to fringe elements who insist on living in the past*
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/live</sub>